# Cucumber World: Error Trying to construct array of h4 elements

Tags: javascript, dom, cucumber, puppeteer

In cucumber world. js file I am trying to construct an array of h4 elements as shown in code
Iam getting the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined. Not sure what is wrong. TIA

```js
   async deleteFileByTitle(fileTitle, wait = 0) {

      await this.page.waitFor(wait);

      const h4NodeList = this.page.document.querySelectorAll('h4');


      const h4Array = Array.from(h4NodeList);
```

Comment: I am the OP. I think I should use  this.page.eval$$ but not sure of the syntax.

Comment: tried this but h4Array[3] was undefined ```const h4Array = await this.page.evaluate(() => {
         [...element] = document.querySelectorAll('h4');
         return [...element];
      });
      console.log(h4Array[3]);```

Comment: const h4Array = await this.page.evaluate(
         () => [...document.querySelectorAll('h4')]);  still getting undefined error if console.log(h4Array[0]

Comment: This seems to work. Not sure why I had to map elements to themselves  const h4Array = await this.page.evaluate(
         () => [...document.querySelectorAll('h4')].map(elem => elem));